# What is this element called? Two dimensional checkbox/radiobox?

Tags: flutter, checkbox, radio-button, element

I'm developing a Flutter app and I'm trying to find what this is called:

[image: Thing I'm trying to find]

Essentially, it's a checklist that only allows one input and is two dimensional.

[image: Selection showed]

In this image, the top left box is selected.

I'd appreciate any help in trying to find what this element is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i know in flutter, i don't think flutter has that widget yet. So this is what i do to get around.

I create separate listTiles or boxes or any widget of choice. And in the onpressed/onclicked property, i compared the number assigned to that widget with my global variable and if it's true, set isSelected to true

Works everytime

```
int globalNum=3;
//somewhere in your widget tree
ListTile(
selected:globalNum==1?true:false,
selectedTileColor:Colors.red,
onTap:()=>globalNum=1,
),
ListTile(
selected:globalNum==2?true:false,
selectedTileColor:Colors.red,
onTap:()=>globalNum=2,
),
```

You can wrap your scaffold in a theme so that you don't set the individual selectedTileColor. But for demostration this is how you'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

If the control permits only one item at a time, it's a Radio.  See the docs for details.